# When was the last change of a certian state

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a problem. I want to know when was the last change of a certian state was. For example I have even more columns. I want to know when on which date changed the state. E.g. the last change of a state for id 2 was `2023-04-12 11:00:40`. How could I extract this date?

```py
import pandas as pd

data = {'ID': [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2],
        'state': ['Recording', 'Recording', 'Testing', 'Testing', 'Testing', 'Recording', 'Recording', 'Recording', 'Testing'],
        'change_date': ['2023-08-12T11:00:40', '2023-07-12T11:00:40', '2023-06-12T11:00:40', '2023-10-12T11:00:40', '2023-09-12T11:00:40', '2023-04-12T11:00:40', '2023-03-12T11:00:40', '2023-03-12T11:00:40', '2023-01-12T11:00:40']}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df['change_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['change_date'])

print(df)
```

```py
   ID      state         change_date
0   1  Recording 2023-08-12 11:00:40
1   1  Recording 2023-07-12 11:00:40
2   1    Testing 2023-06-12 11:00:40
3   2    Testing 2023-10-12 11:00:40
4   2    Testing 2023-09-12 11:00:40
5   2  Recording 2023-04-12 11:00:40
6   2  Recording 2023-03-12 11:00:40
7   2  Recording 2023-03-12 11:00:40
8   2    Testing 2023-01-12 11:00:40
```

What I want

```py
ID  last_change   state
1   2023-07-12    Recording 
2   2023-04-12    Testing
```

What I tried

```py
result = df.groupby('ID')['change_date'].max().reset_index()
print(result)

[OUT]
   ID         change_date
0   1 2023-08-12 11:00:40
1   2 2023-10-12 11:00:40
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Compare the current and previous value in the `state` column to flag the rows having changes then filter the rows using the flag and drop the duplicates to keep the most recent change

```
s = df.sort_values(['change_date'])
m = s['state'] != s.groupby('ID')['state'].shift()

s[m].drop_duplicates('ID', keep='last')
```

---

```
   ID      state         change_date
1   1  Recording 2023-07-12 11:00:40
4   2    Testing 2023-09-12 11:00:40
```

Answer (score 2):

Another possible solution:

```
(df.sort_values(['ID', 'change_date'])
 .groupby('ID', as_index=False)
 .apply(lambda g: 
     g.loc[g['state'].ne(g['state'].shift()).cumsum().idxmax(),
           ['state', 'change_date']]))
```

Output:

```
   ID      state         change_date
0   1  Recording 2023-07-12 11:00:40
1   2    Testing 2023-09-12 11:00:40
```

Answer (score 1):

You can shift the dataframe and compare columns' values with the original. If the status has changed, IDs will be the same, but the state will have changed.

After finding rows with changed statuses you can find the last one of those for each ID:

```
df = df \
    .sort_values(["ID", "change_date"]) \
    .reset_index(drop=True)

mask = (df.shift(1) == df)

df[mask["ID"] & ~mask["state"]] \
    .sort_values("change_date") \
    .groupby("ID", as_index=False) \
    .last()
```

Output:

```
   ID      state         change_date
0   1  Recording 2023-07-12 11:00:40
1   2    Testing 2023-09-12 11:00:40
```

P.S. I get slightly different results from what you're expecting, there may be a mixup with which row you want to show in the final dataframe: before status change or after?